# ReactJS get refs/class/id from inside a loop/map to be used in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Can I get reference of class or id or refs of a element which is inside a map function?

```
componentDidMount(){
        console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.items));
}
render(){

    var loop = Object.keys(this.state.posts).map((key) => {
        var post = this.state.posts[key];
        return(
            <div key={key} className="hakuna-matata" ref="items">
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }

    return {loop}
}
```

I would like to access ref=items or class=hakuna-matata array or object in jQuery

Can anyone help? Please

Answer (score 0):

Well, so the content of your `loop` is an array. Collapse the array to a string to get the whole HTML Code.

Second, the question is where do you wish to have jQuery work with the HTML Code.
As long as you are in the render method the code is not in the DOM Tree. So you have to let jQuery parse the code: `var myJqueryNode = $(loop.join());`.

If you are in some kind of event handler in React after the rendering has been performed you can easily query the DOM Tree like: `$('.hakuna-matata');`

Comment: componentDidMount would be the preferable place to use jQuery? At the moment if I try to $('.hakuna-matata'); inside componentDidMount, it is returning the whole DOM of the current page, I would like to do some animations using jQuery on hover event

Comment: Ah, ok. If possible go for CSS Animations - much more performance and in this case easier and better to implement. Otherwise simply use the react event handlers: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events and you can access your component either via pure JS or jQuery...

Comment: I need to get the parent().parent() element of hovered element so I need JS for this else I also prefer CSS for these things, saw mouseEvents on the link you shared with me combined with @jie-trooper answer - using onMouseOver event. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You may do not want to put the `ref` inside the loop because it causes duplication. Instead you can do this:

```
handlePost = (e, post) => {
  //do whatever to post here...
  //do whatever to e here...
}

render(){
    const loop = Object.keys(this.state.posts).map((key) => {
        const post = this.state.posts[key];
        return(
            <div key={key} className="hakuna-matata"
              onClick={(e) => {this.handlePost(e, post}}>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
    return {loop}
}
```

Upon clicking the post, pass the post object to the method `handlePost` and you can do whatever to it without using `refs`. You can also pass `e` or event and access the event object.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I agree with your approach - using onMouseOver event from React Event System (shared by @Kjell below) - the problem now is there is a child of this div e.g. overlay-container and under it text-container, so if I hover, output of e.target gives me these both children simultaneously, I would like to have their parent container - from where the function is triggered. Also, hover event is triggered 2 times because it has 2 divs

Comment: If you say parent, do you mean the parent div that wraps all the post div? If this is the case, wrap a div before you loop and assign a ref to it. You can then use this to access the wrapping div.

Comment: Parent as in this case will be 'hakuna-matata'. DOM tree will be like: hakuna-matata > overlay-container > text-container. So when I am hovering on hakuna-matata - the event 'e' is referring to child elements as well.